# Unable to merge dex : libraries have same package name

Tags: android, gradle

I just stumbled upon this problem when I was using two Android libraries I created :

```
implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:freesmsapi:1.0'
implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:fingerprint:2.5.2'
```

I get the following error :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

If I run the build with the stacktrace option, I get this additional info :

> Multiple dex files define Lme/aflak/libraries/BuildConfig;

So I have the feeling this is happening because the two libraries have **the same package name**. But then how it comes that some of Google's libraries (e.g. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)) have the same package name, and everything goes right ?

**Do you know how I can fix my libraries so I can include several of them in the same project ? Or how can I fix this particular error with gradle ?**

thanks !

P.S. I already tried `multiDexEnabled true`, it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have the feeling this is happening because the two libraries have the same package name.

You are correct. The literal cause is two `BuildConfig` classes in the same Java package. That comes from having the same package name.

> But then how it comes that some of Google's libraries (e.g. Firebase) have the same package name, and everything goes right ?

They probably do not have the same package name (defined as `package` in the root `<manifest>` element of the manifest). Even if they do, they do not ship `BuildConfig`.

> Do you know how I can fix my libraries so I can include several of them in the same project ?

The simplest solution is to change the package name of one of the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I rename the package name of one of the libraries, does that mean that I will have to include it the following way `implementation 'me.aflak.libraries_renamed:fingerprint:2.5.2'` ? Because I would like to keep the same nomenclature.

Comment: @OmarAflak: No, because that's not the package name. That's an artifact group name, and you have that set up somewhere in `build.gradle`. `BuildConfig` is generated at the location identified by the `package` attribute on the `<manifest>` element of the manifest.

Comment: Okay great ! Thank you !